# QGIS field calculator expression returns NULL but preview showing correct value

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, qgis-expression

I have a simple task: get x coordinate (longitude) from end_point of a linestring (the last vertex). I then open the QGIS field calculator in the attributes table and input the following expression: **x(end_point(@geometry))**. Should be quite simple, but when running, all values are NULL while the preview shows the correct values.

I have tried every combination of field type, field length and virtual field. Also tried saving in a different shapefile and geopackage, to see if the file is broken or someting. The thing is: when a try it on a temporary layer it works just fine.

I've come across this problem before with a different expression.
[image: Qgis Field Expression]

Some info:

- QGIS 3.28
- CRS SIRGAS 2000
- Layer MultiLineString (SIRGAS 2000)

Comment: Could it be something to do with the precision?

Comment: You can try with `$geometry` instead of `@geometry`. It seems to be a known [bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50791)

Comment: I get the same behavior as you using 3.28.3 (preview shows the correct values but the field get null value) , I did try the @JGH solution (using  $geometry) and it work as intended (you could also use the simpler $x_at( ) fonction).  So it seem that indeed there is a bug with '@geometry'

Comment: It worked with $geometry instead of @ geometry. @JGH thank you very much.